# Definition of multimodules

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, definition

Let $A,B$ be rings and $h:A\rightarrow\text{End}(E)$, $k:B\rightarrow\text{End}(E)$ two ring homomorphisms. If $h_\alpha\circ k_\beta=k_\beta\circ h_\alpha$ for all $(\alpha,\beta)\in A\times B$, we say that the two (left or right–I have used left) module structures defined on $E$ by $h$ and $k$ are **compatible**.

> Let $(A_\lambda)_{\lambda\in L}$,$(B_\mu)_{\mu\in M}$ be two families
>   of rings. An $((A_\lambda)_{\lambda\in L},(B_\mu)_{\mu\in
>  M})$-multimodule is a set $E$ with, for each $\lambda\in L$, a left
>   $A_\lambda$module structure and, for each $\mu\in M$, a right
>   $B_\mu$-module structure, **all these module structures being compatible
>   with one another**.

Does the bolded portion of this definition imply compatibility amongst the $A_\lambda$ (resp. $B_\mu$) as well? For example does it imply that $A_\lambda$ and $A_{\lambda'}$ are compatible for $\lambda,\lambda'\in L$?

Comment: If you require the compatibility on the same side, then the definition becomes that of a bimodule over the direct products. So my guess would be that there is only meant to be compatibility between the sides.

Comment: The author also says the following: "When the family $(B_\mu)_{\mu\in M}$ is empty, $E$ is called a left multimodule". So if the $A_\lambda$ are not required to be compatible with each other, then, in the case where the family $(B_\mu)_{\mu\in M}$ is empty, what sort of structure would we be dealing with? Just a set $E$ with a bunch of left module structures that have no relation to each other. Would that be of interest to anyone (genuine question)?

Comment: Your definition of compatibility implies immediately that the various $A_{\lambda}$-module structures have to be compatible with each other. Also, a left $A$-module structure is compatible with a right $B$-module structure if the left $A$-module structure is compatible with the left $B^{\mathrm{op}}$-module structure of the opposite ring. So you always check compatibility on one side only.